# Reverse order of events on homepage

Tags: events, the-events-calendar

I'm having problems reversing the order of events that are appearing on my [homepage](http://timetolaugh.ca/). I want them to appear with the next event at the top. I have tried modifying the code in index.php right before the `have_posts()` function as some tutorials suggest, but it doesn't seem to work the same with events as it does posts.

The plugin I'm using for the events is [The Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/).

I've included the code in case someone needs it.

I'm on the latest version of the plugin, and the latest of wordpress. The theme is built on "Point"

```
    <?php $mts_options = get_option('point'); ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="page" class="home-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="article">
            <h3 class="frontTitle">
                        <div class="latest">
                        <?php _e('Upcoming events',"mythemeshop"); ?>           
                        </div></h3>
    <?php   $j=0; $i =0;    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>            
    <article class="<?php echo 'pexcerpt'.$i++?> post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                            <?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('featured',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nothumb.png" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="featured-cat"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></div>
                    </a>
                    <header>                        
                        <h2 class="title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h2>


                    </header><!--.header-->
                    <div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo mts_excerpt(29);?>
                            <span class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Read More','mythemeshop'); ?></a></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="no-results">
                    <h5><?php _e('No results found. We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></h5>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!--Start Pagination-->
            <?php if ( isset($mts_options['mts_pagenavigation']) && $mts_options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1' ) { ?>
                <?php  $additional_loop = 0; global $additional_loop; mts_pagination($additional_loop['max_num_pages']); ?>           
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                        <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <!--End Pagination-->           
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-the-events-calendar-cannot-change-order-of-posts-in-query_posts (scroll down to last code snippet and there's a solution. I havent tested it myself. and it seems kind of a ugnly workaround, but it seems to be an issue with plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something along the lines of using `pre_get_posts` to edit the ordering.

```
function reverse_order_homepage($query){
    if($query->is_home()){
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    }

    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'reverse_order_homepage');
```

Comment: Howdy, this will not work. Taken from the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) codex page: "For example, is_front_page() will not work, although is_home()will work."

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the edited code will work since it is a page?

Comment: I would stick with `is_home()` though. The question states homepage and index.php, so the assumption is that there is no front page set in settings.

Comment: If I had to create a new page that wouldn't be a big deal. Would the above solution work easier if it were on it's own specific page, and not the home page?

Comment: If you know the post ID you can use include `global $post` at the top of the function, and in the IF statement say something along the lines of `if($post->ID == $your_id_here)` that will probably work.